# "SEVERE: There is no installed container capable of handling this application" error while trying to deploy EJB jar in glassfish

Tags: netbeans, ejb, glassfish-3

I am using netbeans 7.2.1 and glassfish 3.1.2 server. I created an ejb project and while trying to deploy the ejb jar in the server, i see the below error in the server log:

```
SEVERE: Module type not recognized for module C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2.1\config\GF3\domain1\applications\SAPLockBox
SEVERE: There is no installed container capable of handling this application SAPLockBox
```

The error also points out to

```
<target if="netbeans.home" name="-run-deploy-nb">
    <nbdeploy debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
</target>
```

in build-impl.xml. I have read many online posts and tried a few but no success so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to run your ejb jar file not in your netbeans context, but outside of it?

What Java EE APIs do you use? You may have one, that it is not accessible to the glassfish server, but in netbeans compiles OK.

Comment: csabee: the problem occured because of an JARfile which was not accepted by glassfish. I removed it which solved the problem.